# Microsoft interview - Image bitmap

Tags: c, algorithm

I was going through old MS questions and came across this one:

> A pic has a bitmap assoc with it and a 256 long array of original
>   palettes. Now we have a change list, where some old colors are mapped
>   onto new colors. Write the code to change the original palette. Now if
>   the original bitmap has to be changed, write the code that will scan
>   the pic as well as the changed palette array. The code should be O(N)
>   and not O(N^2). The struct of the original palette may be changed to
>   accomplish this.

I am unable to figure out the exact problem. If would be great if someone could illustrate the problem and the standard approach. Many thanks.

Comment: Somebody else must have transcribed that problem, badly. That doesn't look like something Microsoft would present to interviewees. Besides, nobody uses palettes anymore, anyway.

Comment: It's a trick question.  All you have to do is change the palette, you don't have to touch the image itself.

Comment: flood fill algorithm maybe?  I know they still ask this question

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of questions should be addressed with some interaction with the recruiter.

My approach would be the following:

```
for each *element* in *image data*
    if *palette value* in *element* contains *old value*
        update *palette value* with *new value*
    end
    process *element*
end
```

The above may not have updated some values (for the case that there are some palette values that don't exists in the image), but I think that this is an easy approach to handle this problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the palette array by replacing the colors as per the change list.